# Ubuntu Mate Caja Wont Apply Theme After Restart

Tags: themes, mate, restart, caja

I usually set my MATE theme as `ambiant-mate` with `darkmate` color scheme, but when I restart, `caja` wont apply the theme, unless I restart it.

How can i make it so, that it is a permanent change without the need to restart `caja`?